# Why does this filter function return an error in python?

Tags: python

```
list = ['hello','goodbye']
filteredList = list(filter(lambda x: x == "hello", list))
print(filteredList)
```

This returns an error 'list' object is not callable.
Why is this?
Thanks

Comment: Because you're defining you're python `list` with the name `list`. Now you're variable `list`  is masking the built-in `list` class

Comment: Oh yes! Thanks alot, not sure how I didn't see that :)

Answer (score 2):

Rename your `list` variable to something else, like `l`. `list` is already the name of a class in Python.

```py
l = ['hello','goodbye']
shesaid = list(filter(lambda x: x == "AA", l))
print(shesaid)
```